# How to describe a quoted string in EBNF

Tags: ebnf

How do I describe a quoted string (like in C, Java, etc) in EBNF notation?

I was thinking of this (see below), but the AnyCharacter part will also match the double quotes (`"`).

```
QuotedString = '"' AnyCharacter* '"' ;
```

In other words, how do I match all characters except the double quote character (`"`), but still allow escapes (`/"`)?

Comment: [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) describes and documents a syntax, it does not match or parse it. Are you trying to generate EBNF diagrams? Or do you need to look at existing ones? In that case do a web search for the C, Java, or whatever language standards. If you want to parse this, look for a library that understands the given syntax, e.g., a C parser. If it's just about strings, you could write it yourself: walk through the input, and each time you see a slash, treat the following character differently.

Comment: Sorry, the question may need more clarification. Is there a way in EBNF to describe a quoted string, like in C, Java, etc? Question edited.

Comment: Yes, and there are examples scattered across the web--is there additional confusion?

Comment: Sorry, can you point me to one of those examples? Some examples I saw didn't seem to support Unicode characters, which I plan to support...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
string = " printable-chars | nested-quotes "
```

where

```
printable chars = letter | digit | ~ @ # % _ $ & ' - + /
```

where

```
letter = A..Z | a..z | extended ascii
```

and

```
digit = 0..9
```

I think you've got the general idea